# Hiding HTML5 video sources in div tag id attributes

Tags: javascript, html

I’d like to be able to specify my video sources for my toggle button in the HTML document so that I don’t have to include them in the JavaScript code.

I figured out a way to accomplish it by hiding the URLs in div tags as id attributes and then getting them in the JavaScript by their class name. (See below). This seems like a total hack. I’m sure there must be a better way to do this. Any suggestions?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

    <div class="video1" id="http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4"></div>
    <div class="video2" id="http://www.w3schools.com/html/movie.mp4"></div>
    
    <button onclick="Harmonica(this,'myVideo')" type="button"> Video 2</button>

    <video height="auto" width="500"id="myVideo" controls autoplay loop class="myvideo">
    <source id="mp4_src" src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
</body>

<script> 
        var vid = document.getElementById("myVideo");
        var statusElement = document.getElementById("status");
        var currentlyPlaying = 1;
        var currentlPlayingTime;
        
        var src1 = document.getElementsByClassName("video1")[0].id;
        
        var src2 = document.getElementsByClassName("video2")[0].id;
        
        function Harmonica(btn,myVideo) {
            currentlPlayingTime = vid.currentTime;
            if (currentlyPlaying === 1) {
                vid.src = src2;
                currentlyPlaying = 2;
                btn.innerHTML = "Video 1";
            } else {
                vid.src = src1;
                currentlyPlaying = 1;
                btn.innerHTML = "Video 2";
            }
            vid.load();
            vid.addEventListener('canplay', function () {
                vid.currentTime = currentlPlayingTime;
            }, false);
        }
</script>

    

</html>
```

Comment: You can also use the `data-` attribute for attaching arbitrary data.

Comment: What does this accomplish other than not having the video URLs in the JavaScript? All you're doing is adding complexity.

Comment: DigitalDrifter, this is just a small part of a much larger video player code. I’d like to be able to use the same external JavaScript code for dozens of videos on my site without needing to change the video sources for each one and I couldn’t find any other way to do it. Please if you have any better ideas let me know. Thanks!

Comment: This page helped me figure out how to use the data attribute: http://html5doctor.com/html5-custom-data-attributes/